# Bounded Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matrices

Assume $H \in \mathbb{R}_{\mathrm{sym}}^{n \times n}$ with $\left\|H\right\| \leq C_{H}$ with some constant $C_{H}>0$.

What can I say about
$\sup_{d \in B_{\Delta}(0)} \frac{1}{2} d^T H d$?

Does $\sup_{d \in B_{\Delta}(0)} \frac{1}{2} d^THd = \frac{1}{2} C_H \Delta^2$ hold?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is symmetric, it has a full orthogonal complement of eigenvectors and so $$d^\top Hd=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_id_i^2$$
$$\therefore\ |d^\top Hd|\le|\lambda_{max}|\sum_id_i^2=C_H\|d\|^2$$
$$\therefore\ \max_{d\in B_\Delta(0)}|d^\top Hd|=C_H\Delta^2$$
where $C_H=|\lambda_{max}|$ and the maximum is achieved by the eigenvector of $\lambda_{max}$.

However, whether this is equal to $\sup_{d\in B_\Delta(0)}d^\top Hd$ depends on whether the right-most eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ or the left-most eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ has the larger absolute value.

For example, $H=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies the relation $$\sup_{d\in B_\Delta(0)}|d^\top Hd|=2=\|C_H\|\|d\|>1=\sup_{d\in B_\Delta(0)}d^\top Hd$$

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks.